# Doesn't C++ IDE Netbeans or Eclipse support class inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, ide

I am using NetBeans IDE 6.8 to create C++ project. While I use class inheritance, however, it seems to me that it does not recognize the derived class. Here is what I have:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(vector<double> a, double b) {...}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    additionalfunction(...) {...}
};

main()
{
    vector<double> c = something;
    double d = 0;
    B b=B(c, d);
}
```

And the compiler tells me that "B(c,d)" is not declared. I tried Eclipse C++, it told me the same thing. Why is that? Is it because both IDEs do not support C++ inheritance? What should I do?

Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: Are you providing the proper constructor for B?  (i.e. one that takes a vector and double as arguments.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that supporting inheritance is not up to the IDE, but it's the compiler the IDE uses that decides what errors you will get (not all C/C++ compilers are created equal). Where did you get this sample of code, and what IDE did they tell you to use it in? Is it supposed to compile OK? Do you know what compiler NetBeans and Eclipse are using?

Comment: It's gcc. Thanks. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest implementing the constructor in class B.

Answer (score 4):

Subclasses don't inherit constructors.  You're trying to call B(double, double), but there is no B(double, double).  You can define B(double, double), or you can use [this pattern](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8) from the C++ FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, constructors (and destructors) are not inherited like regular methods. You need to define B(vector, double). However, you can perform a sort of call on the parent constructor in the initialization list:

```
public:
    B(vector<double> a, double b) : A(a, b){
        ...
    }
```